# IndyHandle to TIDPEERTHREAD

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy, indy-9

I am using Indy9 with Delphi7.
I would like to cast an Longword (Athread.Handle) back to an TIDPEERTHREAD Pointer.
Is there a way how I could do this?
Or is there any other way I could "store" the Pointer to a Longword?

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TIdPeerThread` is a `TThread` descendant. Its `Handle` property contains the OS-level thread handle from `CreateThread()`.  There is no way to cast a `Handle` value directly to a `TIdPeerThread` object pointer.  You will have to either:

1) Store the `TIdPeerThread` object pointer itself in the `LongWord` instead of the `TIdPeerThread.Handle` value, and then cast it back when needed:

```
var
  LW: LongWord;
  Peer: TIdPeerThread;

Peer := ...;
LW := LongWord(Peer);
...
Peer := TIdPeerThread(LW);
```

2) Store the `TIdPeerThead.Handle` value in the `LongWord`, then loop through the `TIdTCPServer.Threads` list looking for a `TIdPeerThread` object that has a matching value when needed:

```
var
  LW: LongWord;
  Peer: TIdPeerThread;
  List: TList;
  I: Integer;

Peer := ...;
LW := LongWord(Peer.Handle);
...
Peer := nil; 
List := IdTCPServer1.Threads.LockList;
try
  for I := 0 to List.Count-1 do
  begin
    if LongWord(TIdPeerThread(List[I]).Handle) = LW then
    begin
      Peer := TIdPeerThread(List[I]);
      Break;
    end;
  end;
finally
  IdTCPServer1.Threads.UnlockList;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you show me a small example how I could store TIdPeerThread into a Longword and cast it back? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have updated my answer, but did I really need to show you how to typecast a pointer to an integer and back?  That is Delphi 101 programming (OK maybe 102).